# Shifting points along normal vector to path

Tags: qgis, mapping, land-survey

I have list of points which are connected with line in "zig-zag" fashion:

[image: example]

Using QGIS, I'm trying to create a line connecting all the middle or inside points and then shift all outside points to this middle line along normal vector. 
End result is a single line with all points plotted on this line.

Note that intervals could be irregular and I can't simply divide middle line in equal portions and create new points.

Which QGIS tools would be appropriate for this task?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, are the lines between the points individual segments or do the line segments encompass many points?

Comment: Line segment contains many points. Note that line on provided picture was created by me just for display purposes. My data is list of unique points with x and y. 
End result has to be all points shifted to this imaginary middle line.

Comment: Try creating a minimum bounding geometry, then skeletonize it, then select and delete any dangling lines based on line length.